# Scrape 'new' Flag from Span Using BS4

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've seen similar questions regarding the text from a span tag but I can't seem to get this to work. I'm speculating/guessing its because I'm dropping part of the line out earlier in the script but am not sure. I'm scraping Indeed and want to know whether they are flagging jobs as 'new'. Apologies for the screenshot but I'm trying to keep the question clean.

The goal is to return the the below data and the text of 'new' from the highlighted span.

[image: HTML Inspection]

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Title","Location","Company","Salary","Descr","New_Flag"])
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, 'html.parser', from_encoding="utf-8")
        for item in soup.find_all(class_= "result" ):
            try: 
                title = item.find(class_='jobtitle').text.replace('\n', '')
            except:
                title = None
            try:
                location = item.find('span', {'class':"location" }).text.replace('\n', '')
            except:
                location = None
            try: 
                company = item.find(class_='company').text.replace('\n', '')
            except:
                company = None
            try:
                salary = item.find('span', {'class':'no-wrap'}).text
            except:
                salary = None
            try:
                descr = item.find('span', {'class':'summary'}).text.replace('\n', '')
            except:
                descr = None
            try:
                new_flag = item.find('span', {'class':'new'}).text
            except:
                new_flag = None
```

I'm not receiving any errors but I'm also not receiving any results in the data frame. It works if I remove the new_flag component.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried `.find_all` in search for the `span` tag? `new_flag  = item.find_all('span', attrs={'class': 'new'})`.

Comment: Do you mean find_all to replace item.find within the loop?